# Разработка общих библиотек для нескольких приложений в проекте

Tags: проектирование, обработка-ошибок, webapi, разделяемые-библиотеки

Проект, который я решил создать будет состоять из трех приложений:

- Telegram bot
- API для мобильных приложений
- Веб приложение

У всех трех приложений будет общая библиотека работы с логикой БД и модель, так сказать единая точка входа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод Save возвращает last inserted id, то есть Id нового пользователя.

Предположим, что на стороне SQL возникла исключительная ситуация, мы ее обрабатываем и через out параметры возвращаем код ошибки и сообщение (например, code:150, message:"Error saving user..."

Понятно, что метод Save вернет значение 0, так как пользователь не сохранился.
**Если в проектах Telegram Bot и Web App мы можем проверить возвращаемое значение на 0 и выдать сообщение об ошибке, то как быть с API?** **Мне ведь нужно отправить клиенту JSON такого вида:**

```
{
  "code" : 150,
  "message": "Error saving user...."
}
```

Проекты пишу на C#. Есть несколько вариантов как реализовать универсальное решение: через out параметры, либо через единый у всех методов возвращаемый объект, класс которого будет иметь 3 свойства, Result, Code, Message

Хотелось бы узнать рекомендации к такому подходу разработки приложений

Answer (score 1):

Естественная рекомендация — применять исключения (exceptions).

В случае возникновения ошибки надо выбрасывать исключение с помощью оператора `throw`. В подавляющем большинстве случаев можно обрабатывать все исключения программы на самом высоком уровне.

В Web App можно обработчик может показывать страницу со статусом 500. В REST API можно также возвращать статусы 400 или 500 и JSON с описанием ошибки.

Вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) о том, как встраивать обработчик исключений в приложения Web App или API.

А вот [описание](https://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects), как может выглядеть описание ошибки в JSON. Это из набора соглашений, который называется JSON API.